# Firefox Add-on SDK open tab on first run

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the Firefox Add-on SDK, and I am attempting to open a tab as soon as my Firefox extension gets installed for the first time. The code below is in my main.js, but it doesn't seem to work. Any tips?

main.js:

```
var ss = require("simple-storage");
var tabs = require('tabs');

if (typeof(ss.storage.firstRun) === undefined) {
    ss.storage.firstRun = false;
    alert('First run');
    tabs.open("http://www.google.com"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the load install reason: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/load-and-unload.html

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct but the `typeof` operator gives you a string so you have to compare it to a string:

```js
if (typeof ss.storage.firstRun == "undefined") {
```

This way it should work.